# Typescript drop event, event is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

For my website i'm using .net core 2 with angular. So i'm working on this login system but i can't get my head around some stuff.

I'm using the angular Guard to protect my pages from unauthorized access. I also have a userservice to get the current logged in user from the .net core 2 backend. My Guard looks into the userservice to find the current user, if there is no user we make a call to get the current user. If there is no current authorized user it redirects the user to the login page. This all works fine, except for the fact that the code continues while we are still getting the user from the server, resulting in a not logged in user everytime.

Guard:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.userService.user == undefined) {
        this.userService.RefreshUser();
        console.log("did i wait?");
    }

    if (this.userService.IsAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("you are logged in");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return false;
}
```

so the userService.RefreshUser() finds the user with an api call:

```
 public RefreshUser() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "api/Account/GetCurrentUser").subscribe(result => {
        try {
            this.SetUser(JSON.stringify(result.json()));
            console.log("user refreshed");
        }
        catch(e){

        }

    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

but it does not wait for the user to be retrieved. I put in 2 console logs and the "Did i wait?" get triggered before the "User refreshed" one. How can i make the rest of the code wait untill the user has been set in the userservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's asynchronous. Use `async` and `await` :

```
async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.userService.user == undefined) {
        await this.userService.RefreshUser();
        console.log("did i wait?");
    }

    if (this.userService.IsAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("you are logged in");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return false;
}

 public async RefreshUser() {
    try {
        const user = await this.http
            .get(this.baseUrl + "api/Account/GetCurrentUser")
            .map(result => JSON.stringify(result.json()))
            .toPromise()

        this.SetUser(user);
        console.log("user refreshed");
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried async before, didn't know about the map and promise part! This works perfectly!